# React change state of checkbox

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Class component - list of items with a boolean property ; I've added onChange method to change state of this propery in a collection. When I try to compile I have:

> Line 15:59:  Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow
> function  array-callback-return

```
import React from "react";

class ItemList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       items: props.items
    }
  }

  toggleCompleted = (position) => {
    const updatedItems = this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
      position === idx ? {...item, completed: !item.completed} : item //err
    })
    this.setState({
      items: updatedItems
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="col-12 col-lg-8 mx-auto">
      <h3 className="h3">Tasks</h3>
      {this.state.items.length > 0 &&
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Completed</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
          return (
            <tr key={idx+1}>
              <th scope="row">{idx+1}</th>
              <td>{item.title}</td>
              <td>{item.description}</td>
              <td>
                <input 
                id={"completed".concat(idx)} 
                className="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={item.completed}
                onChange={() => {this.toggleCompleted(idx)}}/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      }
    </div>
    )
  }
}


export default ItemList;
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Add missing return statement:

```
const updatedItems = this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
  return position === idx ? {...item, completed: !item.completed} : item 
})
```

or remove `{}`

```
const updatedItems = this.state.items.map((item, idx) =>
  position === idx ? {...item, completed: !item.completed} : item 
)
```

Read more about basics [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Add a "return" before

```
position === idx ? {...item, completed: !item.completed} : item
```